# React Hook Form Watch on Select Field

Tags: reactjs

I have trouble with the Select field.

When I use the watch on select HTML attribute and change options in it, it doesn't re-render in the console. it stays the same, but when I use onChange, its re-renders.

My example of code --->

```
const example = watch('skills')
console.log(watch('skills'))
console.log(example)
<select {...register( 'skills')}>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

when I choose option 2, it doesn't show option 2. what should I do? thanks

Comment: What is `watch`? What is `register`?

Comment: it is in React Hook Form

Answer (score -1, accepted):

React hook form does not work with select forms correctly (no optimization).

Comment: It works with select forms, here is an example https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Registerfields

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
const watchShowAge = watch('primaryType');
...
{ watchShowAge === 10 && (<p>You are too young!</p>) }
```